# How does one say "Polar bear cub" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

How would Polar bear cub be spoken in German?  I know Eisbär is polar bear, but can't figure out the proper way to describe the young.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Eisbärjunges

A generic term for an infant animal is [*"das Junge / ein Junges"*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Junges).

Comment: There are many sources for [Eisbärjunges at Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=Eisb%C3%A4rjunges)

Comment: @knut -- I tried google, yes it's easy to google the german term, but it's not easy to get to it from an english search.  For instance google translate never gave me that no matter what I tried and it gave me stuff I *knew* was wrong.

Comment: @DudeOnRock - Thanks for the tip about the generic junges.